# DropMenu from iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a toolbar for chrome and i have some issues with my dropMenu. So basicelly my toolbar bar is a iframe, and i want to put a dropmenu in it. But the problem is that my dropmenu only stay in the iframe and what i want is that it overflow out of the iframe.

Let me show you a printscreen of my wish :

http://img713.imageshack.us/i/iframe.png/

Comment: I don't think you can do that from inside an iframe.

Comment: can you use a div instead of an iframe?

Comment: @Sindar, can you explain why?

Comment: Because i need to represent my toolbar with my iframe. You can't do that with a div...

I mean, its an injection that i make in every web page that i'm visit ;)

Comment: @Sindar, fair enough, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about a Chrome extension or plain old HTML?

If HTML, are you able to do the opposite and make the main page your toolbar with a huge `<iframe>` containing the main website. This is how StumbleUpon structures their layout and [their toolbar has dropdown menus](http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/6aXfTW/).

Realise though that any website that employs frame-busting code (like Facebook, Twitter and StackExchange network websites) won't ever be able to be toolbar-ed.

Comment: I'm talking about a google chrome extensio who inject toolbar on each web Page. I will me something like StumbleUpon yeah... But for me its another iframe injection.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only hope is to make the `iframe` as high as the drop down is, and use a transparent background on your `iframe` with `allowtransparency="true"`.

For want of a better link, see:

http://www.htmlite.com/SD009b.php
http://www.htmlite.com/trans_iframe1.html

Comment: and { position:absolute; top: 0px }